# DataNucleus - HashMultimap datastore created as mediumblob

Tags: jdo, datanucleus

I am trying to use the type HashMultimap in one of my entity object.

```
@Persistent
private HashMultimap<String, String> testMap;
```

JDO

```
<field name="testMap" persistence-modifier="persistent" serialized="false">
    <join />
</field>
```

However when i run schema tools with DataNuclues, the field is created as a mediumblob. My question is whether i can force this to be create as a join table.

What i am after is basically a data type of a hashmap that can support duplicate key value.

I am using MySQL as datastore

Thanks

Comment: Fair guess is that this type, whatever it is, is not supported, so it falls back to serialised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andy from DataNucleus

HashMultimap is not supported in the default package